# Trying to get lotusscript json reader

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Through LotusScript I am consuming a webpage that returns json values and I have been unable to find any library out there for lotusscript, other than ls.snapps.JSONReader from openntf.  It works, but documentation is limited.  I am having trouble reading a nested array in the value list.  I was able to get it to work in java using the ibm.common.utils.... library, but was having trouble with mac client and another library (javax.swing.*) so I switched to LotusScript.

I am hoping someone else has experience with the ls.snapps.JSONReader library, or maybe a different idea on how to do this.  Here is the sample:

to read it I use

```
Dim jsonReader As jsonReader
Dim vResults As Variant
Dim vPieces As Variant
Dim sJSON As string
sJson= |{   "colorsArray":[{
            "red":"#f00",
            "green":"#0f0",
            "blue":"#00f",
            "cyan":"#0ff",
            "magenta":"#f0f",
            "yellow":"#ff0",
            "black":"#000"
        }
    ]
}|

Set jsonReader = New JsonReader
Set vResults = jsonReader.parse(sJson)
vPieces = vResults.items
```

I have no trouble when I set a single level object such as:

```
sJSON = |{"a":"a4255524","a24":true,"ax":"WER!!","b":"Some text"}|
```

I use the getItemValue method

```
msgbox vResults.getitemValue("a24")
```

will return a 'true' value

Has anyone used this JSON parser and can you give me some advice on how to get the data out?

---

UPDATE and interim solution:
To get json values I had to do one of two things:

- use ls Replace functions to extract the single dimension data (ie, remove {"colorsArray":[  on the left side and ]}  on the right side., then use snapps json reader.
- I created a java library using the SBT JSON libs and called it from LotusScript.  Paul Bastide put a good writeup on using the java lib http://bastide.org/2014/03/15/using-the-ibm-social-business-toolkit-to-process-json-objects/

Here is the java code:

```
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonException;
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaFactory;
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject;
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser;
import com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.datahandlers.JsonDataHandler;
import lotus.domino.*;
public class GetJSON extends AgentBase  {
    public static String pJSON( String jData, String jEntry, String jValue ) {
        String result2="";
        try {
            System.out.println("data: " + jData + "\n" + "\n" + "jEntry &     jValue: " + jEntry + ", " + jValue);
            // print to debug console
            // System.out.println("jData: " + jData);
            JsonJavaObject jsonObject = (JsonJavaObject) JsonParser.fromJson(JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx, jData );
            JsonDataHandler handler = new JsonDataHandler();
            handler.setData(jsonObject);
            JsonJavaObject entryJson=handler.getEntry(jEntry);
            result2=entryJson.getAsString(jValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            result2="";
        }
        return result2; }
}
```

and I call it from LotusScript as follows:

```
Option Public
Option Declare
Use "($getJson)"
UseLSX "*javacon"

Dim mySession  As JavaSession
Dim myClass As JavaClass
Dim getJson As JavaObject
result = ""
'....
'add vars here
'....
Set mySession = New JavaSession()
Set myClass = mySession.GetClass("GetJSON")
Set GetJson = myClass.CreateObject()


MsgBox GetJson.pJSON( result2, "colorsArray", "red" )
```

IMPORTANT NOTE on the above, in the array string I had to remove the brackets [ and ] because I was getting an SBT array incompatibility error in java.  I think by doing that it may have turned it into a single level object, but if you look at Paul's example from above URL, you'll see he doesn't add them to his example either.

I would rather do this in all Java or all LotusScript, and will probably use the modified json string with snapps, just looking for a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you inspect vPieces?

Comment: For 1 dimension vresults is a variant with is a list with 7 members (M_DATA, M_ICOUNT, REPLACE_CR, REPLACE_BLANK, ...)  M_DATA  is a variant list that contains the name/value pair.  This is the example I have no trouble with.  

With 2 level object VPIECES is a variant object with 1 value , colorsArray (VARIANT) but 5 members (M_VDATA, M_ICOUNT, M_STHREADLIST, M_SERRORMESSAGE, M_IERRORCOUNT) .  M_VDATA is a VARIANT that contains 1 VARIANT [0] AND VALUE [7,"",0], and item [0] contains the 7 items (M_VDATA, M_ICOUNT ...etc) where M_VDATA is a variant list that contains the name/value pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code for your JSON string. Try it.

```
Dim jsonReader As JSONReader
Dim vResults As Variant
Dim vPieces As Variant
Dim sJSON As String
sJson= |{   "colorsArray":[{
        "red":"#f00",
        "green":"#0f0",
        "blue":"#00f",
        "cyan":"#0ff",
        "magenta":"#f0f",
        "yellow":"#ff0",
        "black":"#000"
    }
]}|

Set jsonReader = New JSONReader
Set vResults = jsonReader.parse(sJson)

Set vResultData = vResults.GetItemValue("colorsArray")      
Forall vResult In vResultData.Items
    Msgbox Cstr(vResult.GetItemValue("red"))
    Msgbox Cstr(vResult.GetItemValue("green"))  
    Msgbox Cstr(vResult.GetItemValue("blue"))   
    Msgbox Cstr(vResult.GetItemValue("cyan"))   
    Msgbox Cstr(vResult.GetItemValue("magenta"))    
    Msgbox Cstr(vResult.GetItemValue("yellow")) 
    Msgbox Cstr(vResult.GetItemValue("black"))          
End Forall
```

Comment: Murugavel, that works, thank you very much.  But, how do i get a specific value from a specific row?  Do I need to populate a multidimensional array and then pull the value from there?  Or, is there a way to tell it to get row 1, value of blue?  Right now I am working with 1 row of data, but later can be many rows.

Something like 

    'vRow = sJson.getFirstItem()' or 

vRow=sJson.getItemValue("colorsArray") and then use 

vRow.getitemValue("blue").  

I can iterate through the values and then pick out what i want, but was hoping there was a way to tell it the row and item name.  Thanks again

Comment: Hi,

Use subscripts for the Items object. see below. 


`code`Msgbox vResultData.Items(0).GetItemValue("red")`code`