# How to iterate Key names in a JSON object in lotusscript (ls.snapps.JSONReader)

Tags: json, lotusscript

Related question:
[Trying to get lotusscript json reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820010/trying-to-get-lotusscript-json-reader/43721902#43721902)

How can we iterate the key names if we don't know the keys before in a JSon Object? In case of non array.

```
{   "colorsArray":{
        "red":"#f00",
        "green":"#0f0",
        "blue":"#00f",
        "cyan":"#0ff",
        "magenta":"#f0f",
        "yellow":"#ff0",
        "black":"#000" ,
        .....
    }
}
```

like if vResult.Key exists?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through the 'colorsArray' and you do not know the keys then you can make something like this:

```
Dim jsonReader As JSONReader
Dim vResults As Variant
Dim vPieces As Variant, vResultData  As variant
Dim sJSON As String
sJson= |{   "colorsArray":[{
    "red":"#f00",
    "green":"#0f0",
    "blue":"#00f",
    "cyan":"#0ff",
    "magenta":"#f0f",
    "yellow":"#ff0",
    "black":"#000"
}
]}|

Set jsonReader = New JSONReader
Set vResults = jsonReader.parse(sJson)

Set vResultData = vResults.GetItemValue("colorsArray")      
ForAll vResult In vResultData.Items
    Forall tmp In vResult.Items         
        Print "Key: " +  ListTag(tmp) + " Value: " + tmp    
    End ForAll
End ForAll
```

And if you want to check if some key exists then write a function:

```
Function isKeyAvailable(items As Variant, keyName As String) As Boolean
    If IsElement ( items(keyName) ) Then
        isKeyAvailable = true
    Else
        isKeyAvailable = false
    End If
End Function
```

and then you can check if key exists:

```
...
Set vResultData = vResults.GetItemValue("colorsArray")      
ForAll vResult In vResultData.Items
    If isKeyAvailable(vResult.Items, "green") Then
        Print "Exist"
    Else
        Print "Does not exist"
    End If
End ForAll
...
```

If you are not familiar with Lists in Lotusscript this link will help you:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_WORKING_WITH_LISTS.html

Comment: Thanks for answering this. If it's not an array in case of a JSON object like: sJson= |{   "colorsArray":{
    "red":"#f00",
    "green":"#0f0",
    "blue":"#00f",
    "cyan":"#0ff",
    "magenta":"#f0f",
    "yellow":"#ff0",
    "black":"#000"
}
}|  I suppose we can use ListTag(vResult) to list keys in ForAll loop? It didn't work for me.